# Flutter Simulator Error While Having a Dropdown Which takes values from firebase collection

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, simulator

Can anyone help me regarding this error. I have a dropdown in my application which takes its menu items from a firebase collection. This error only comes in simulator and need help regarding this. Sometimes it works and sometimes it gives errors. Any solutions to this. The error is there for both Android and iOS.

Here is my code for the dropdown menu which takes its items from firebase collection

```
            Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("test").snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData)
              const Text("Loading");
            else {
              List<DropdownMenuItem> occupationItems = [];
              for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.docs.length; i++) {
                DocumentSnapshot snap = snapshot.data.docs[i];
                occupationItems.add(
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text(
                      snap.id,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                    value: "${snap.id}",
                  ),
                );
              }
              return DropdownButtonFormField(
                validator: (value) =>
                    value.isEmpty ? 'Select your occupation' : null,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                ),
                icon: FaIcon(
                  FontAwesomeIcons.chevronCircleDown,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  size: 20.0,
                ),
                items: testItems,
                onChanged: (testValue) {
                  setState(
                    () {
                      test = testValue;
                    },
                  );
                },
                value: test,
                hint: Text(
                  "test",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed return:

```
builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData)
          const Text("Loading");  //// No return here
        else {
          List<DropdownMenuItem> occupationItems = [];
          for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.docs.length; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace this in your if condition inside the stream builder

```
if(snapshot.data == null || snapshot.data.docs.length == 0 || snapshot.hasError ){
 return Text('loading');
}
```